# Django - Create User with Additional Profile Fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users

I've got a view where I collect user data and save it to the backend.

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print("REQUEST", request.user)
        request.session['user'] = request.user.id
        return redirect('additional_info')
else:
    form = UserSignUpForm()
return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Once this is complete, I redirect the user to another page where they can provide additional info in another form for their profile like their dob, profile pic etc.

This uses the following code for the view:

```
def additionalInfo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        user = request.session.get('user')
        if form.is_valid():
             profile = Profile()
             profile.dob = request.POST.get('dob')
             profile.User = user
             profile.save()
             return redirect('app-home')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'users/addInfo.html', {'form': form})
```

The problem is when I try to save the second form I get the exception:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id
```

I'm guessing this is because I have this defined in my `Profile` model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

meaning I need to supply the `user` for which I want to create this `profile`. How do I obtain the info of the `user` who was just registered using the `register` view and make it available in the `additionalInfo` view?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the Users Id as a session variable and pick it up in the other view.

so in your first view add

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
request.session['user'] = user
```

In the second view add

```
profile = Profile()
profile.User = request.session.get('user') 
# Add any more fields you need. get them form request.POST.get('otherfield')
profile.save()
```

Make sure in settings.py you have 'django.contrib.sessions', in your apps
and   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', in your middleware

Comment: How would I then include that user in my code to make sure it is combined with the data from the ProfileForm?

Comment: I'm getting `None` as the `request.user.id` in the `additionalInfo` view - when i log it before setting it in the `register` view I get `AnonymousUser`

Comment: I've updated the question with my current code.

Comment: try just request.user

Comment: its AnonymousUser - I think the issue is that when the account is registered the user isn't actually logged in by the system. Is there a way to force the login upon registration?

Comment: Can you post your forms.py please

Comment: @Alk updated to add authentication after registration

Answer (score 0):

Python is [case sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity#In_programming_languages)

Instead of

> profile.User = user

,according to the model, it should be

```py
profile.user = user
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by importing

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

and inside of the `register` view:

```
user = form.save()
login(request, user)
```

finally, inside of `addiitionalInfo` view user is available at `request.user`